# How do I convert the string to integer javascript so that it supports ie 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, internet-explorer, parseint

My code is like this :

```
  setCol (param) {
    // missing forEach on NodeList for IE11
    if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
      NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }
    const allDates = document.querySelectorAll('.v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content')
    const dates = this.availableDates.map(x => parseInt(x.split('-')[2]))
    allDates.forEach((x, i) => {
      console.log(x.innerHTML) // example : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 etc
      console.log(parseInt(x.innerHTML)) // in firefox, chrome, it works. it return value. example : 1. But in ie 11, it return NaN
      if (dates.indexOf(parseInt(x.innerHTML)) !== -1) {
        console.log('a')
      } else {
        console.log('b')
      }
    })
  },
```

This problem only occurs in the browser ie. I look for references and try like this :

```
parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10)
```

and

```
Number(x.innerHTML)
```

and

```
x.innerHTML * 1
```

But it's the same, the `console.log(parseInt(x.innerHTML))` return `NaN`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using DOM methods like `querySelectorAll` in a Vue app. It's better to drive everything with data and state.

Comment: I suspect part of the issue is using `NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;`. try iterating the NodList using conventional loop approaches

Comment: Can you post the related html resources (the elements with `.v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content` class name)? First, try to set the debugger to check whether you could get all the dates. Then, in the French statement, make sure you could get the selected date via the innerHtml property, Besides, even if you could get the InnerHtml property, please check the value, make sure it doesn't contain the '-' in the date.

Comment: @Phil Why? It works. This problem only occurs in IE

Comment: @charlietfl that code comes from the [official MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill)

Comment: @charlietfl I use that to support forEach. In my opinion this problem occurs here : `parseInt(x.innerHTML)`

Comment: @Zhi Lv This problem only occurs in IE. In my opinion this problem occurs here : `parseInt(x.innerHTML)`. I had console.log and I get all the dates

Comment: Can you tell us the result if using the `console.log(x.innerHTML) ` command in IE browser?

Comment: @Zhi Lv - MSFT Example : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 etc

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem. You could also check the sample in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) in IE browser, the parseInt method works well in IE11 browser.  As we all known, if the value first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number or the radix is smaller than 2 or bigger than 36, the parseInt() method will return NaN. So,the issue is related to the value to parse, try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), then add breakpoint and use F12 developer tools to debug the code step by step, make sure the value is correct.

Comment: If still not find the real reason or solve the problem, Can you post the related html resources (the elements with .v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content class name)? Thus, we could according to your code to reproduce the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The JS Number Prototype should be able to handle this for you. I tried in IE11 dev console the following:

```js
var numberString = "1234";
var toNumber = Number(numberString);
console.log(typof(toNumber));
// console.log result: "number"
```

So this should work with your example. But I don't know if you try to do too manuy things at once in your code. I have made an exmaple on how I would paramaterize this :) Let me know if it works.

```js
allDates.forEach((x, i) => {
      var innerString = x.innerHtml
      var numberFromInner = Number(innerString);
      if (dates.indexOf(numberFromInner) !== -1) {
        console.log('a')
      } else {
        console.log('b')
      }
    })
```

Comment: I had try your code. But it's the same. The result of  `console.log(numberFromInner) ` is `NaN`

Comment: I have made a spelling error so hopefully you didn't ctrl-c ctrl-v the whole thing? :P `x.innterHtml` should be `innerHtml` :D

Comment: And on that note - if you use my code example and console log first the "innerString" - just to make a sanity check for the string that we're trying to convert here